# Something very strange happen to my server today

Tags: linux

If I type `cd ~username` it will say

```
Can't find /home2/username
```

Actually `~username` exists, in `/home3`, and it used to work. Nothing strange has happened. Somehow Linux thinks that all of my `/home2` files are in `/home3` and all my `/home3` files are in `/home2`. Yesterday it worked fine. Then I saw:

```
    root     pts/6        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug 29 05:48   still logged in
    root     pts/5        ng1.cptxoffice.n Thu Aug 29 05:43   still logged in
    root     pts/4        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug 29 05:35   still logged in
    root     pts/3        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug 29 05:31   still logged in
    root     pts/2        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug 29 05:12   still logged in
    root     pts/1        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug 29 02:20   still logged in
    root     pts/0        139.193.156.125  Thu Aug 29 01:34   still logged in
    reboot   system boot  2.6.32-279.22.1. Wed Aug 28 17:00 - 05:48  (12:48)
    reboot   system boot  2.6.32-279.22.1. Wed Aug 28 11:33 - 16:46  (05:13)
    root     pts/0        139.193.156.125  Mon Aug 26 05:12 - 01:23  (20:11)
    root     pts/0        139.193.156.125  Wed Aug 21 20:51 - 22:07  (01:15)
    root     pts/1        139.193.156.125  Wed Aug 21 06:50 - 22:01  (15:11)
```

I do not know of the host `ng1.cptxoffice.net`.

How do I tell linux that `~freemark` belong to `/home2` or `/home3`?

I can temporarily fix the problem by putting a soft link from `/home2` to `/home3` and vice versa. But why this happened in the first place is beyond understanding.

Comment: You should investigate who last changed `/etc/passwd`. If someone is logged in from a host that is unknown to you, it's probably an attacker.

Comment: the password is not changed

Comment: Actually `/etc/passwd` doesn't have any passwords (any more) it contains user information, among which the home directory for each user.

Comment: Run `last` to see who/what has been logging in if there is suspicions of an attack.

Comment: For reference, cptxoffice.net is cPanel's Texas office

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to know what your account's home directory has been set to. That can be found by issuing:

```
getent passwd username | cut -d: -f6
```

(where `username` is your username). I would imagine it would be something like `/home/username`. It may be `/home3/username` in which case you need to set your home directory with:

```
usermod -d /home2/username username
```

(you will have to run this as the root user, or using `sudo` to run it as root, if you have
access in the sudoers file):

```
sudo usermod -d /home2/username username
```

If the above is not the case, and if the `getent` command returned your home directory as `/home`, you need to see if `/home` is already a symlink:

```
ls -ld /home
```

If the output is of the form (showing that of a symlink, and that resolves to home3):

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  root  4 Aug 29 13:37 home@ -> home3
```

Then there is already a symlink that points to home3, and you need to change that.

```
rm /home ; ln -sf /home2 /home3
```

As to diagnosing the issue, if you have access to the root account, check the `~root/.bash_history` file, as I would imagine that user changed the paths. You may also want to kill that login session by issuing:

```
ps ua | grep '[p]ts/5'
```

you should get output that looks something like:

```
root    19687  0.0  0.1  26896  9732 pts/5    Ss+  Aug20   0:00 -bash
```

and then you can terminate the session by passing the associated process id (the 2nd column from the ps command output) to the `kill` command:

```
kill -15 19687
```

Allowing root access remotely is, as a rule, very bad practice. It is recommended to use a non-root account and sudo to gain root access from remote hosts. Also exposing the root account **and** setting `PasswordAuthentication yes` is really bad practice, *especially* if you have a weak password as it can be brute forced and your host compromised (as may have happened to you here).

Provided you have a non-root account, with remote access to the host and permissions in sudo to run all commands as root, I would also recommend changing your root password, `sudo passwd` and changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to have the setting `PermitRootLogin no`, so remote hosts cannot connect as the root user. You will have to restart sshd if
this is set with:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

(that may be `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` depending on your OS). In future if you need a root shell, ssh to the host as your non-root user, and run `exec sudo bash` to get a root shell.